# ARM assembly access to C global variable

Tags: c, assembly, arm

According to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0056d/Cihcciij.html
, if my ARM assembly code need to access a C global variable named `globvar`, I should use `import` and `load` instructions like that:

```
    AREA     globals,CODE,READONLY
    EXPORT    asmsubroutine
    IMPORT    globvar
asmsubroutine
    LDR  r1, =globvar   ; read address of globvar into
                        ; r1 from literal pool
    LDR  r0, [r1]
    ADD  r0, r0, #2
    STR  r0, [r1]
    MOV  pc, lr
    END
```

, but when I use it in my code, there is an error as `"bad instruction`import globvar'"`.
I'm using armv7-android-gcc compiler.  I also looked for the analogous problem in this forum, but I get no useful result, so could anybody help me out of this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn't use the keyword `extern`?

Comment: Do you actually have a variable named `globvar`?  Where does it live?

Comment: You shouldn't need any kind of "IMPORT" directive. Just use the name of the global. BTW the syntax you're using (up to the function name label) does not look like the correct assembler syntax to pass to `as`.

Comment: Please state what assembler you are using and what the command line is.

Comment: yes, i have a variable named globvar, it is defined in a .c file, and i defined it like that: int globvar = 1;

Comment: the assembler is  android-gcc

Comment: @Sophia_Meng Does `globvar` have the keyword `static` associated with it?

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey  no, it not

Comment: @Sophia_Meng In C, you'd use `extern int globvar;`.  In assembly, at least for the STM32 ARM Cortex-M3, you'd use `EXTERN globvar`.

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey yes, you are right, i should use .EXTERN globvar. now the result is correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXTERN globvar` instead of `IMPORT globvar`.