# Import of linker symbols for inline assembler in Rust

Tags: arm, rust, inline-assembly, linker-scripts

I want to access a linker symbol defined in the linker file in inline assembler in Rust for an ARM target. However,

```
asm!(".import mysymb");
```

leads to

> error: :1:2: error: unknown directive
>           .import mysymb

Using `.extern` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366004/arm-assembly-access-to-c-global-variable)) results in:

> LLVM ERROR: unsupported relocation on symbol

What is the correct way to introduce this symbol?

Comment: It appears you are using GNU AS, you don't to do anything to import an external symbol, just use it (with the correct relocation type).